# How to access uploaded files in express js

Tags: angularjs, express

I have a file uploaded from angularjs using ng-file-upload. I send some other data along with the file. I can access that data with `req.query`. How do I access the file in the server side.

When I `console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body))`, the log is empty(`{}`).

Code to upload in controller:

```
Upload.upload({
            url: $scope.ipForHttp+"addVehicles?ClassificationID=" + $scope.C.ClassificationID + "&ClassName=" +
                    $scope.C.ClassName + "&ClassRate=" + $scope.C.ClassRate + "&ClassImage=0"+"&ClientID=1", 
            data:{file:$scope.file} 

            })
```

The server code:

```
app.post('/addVehicles',function(req,res){


console.log("REQ "+req.body.data);
console.log("req"+ JSON.stringify(req.body));
console.log(req.body.file +" Image");
var ClassificationID= req.query.ClassificationID;
var ClassName= req.query.ClassName;
var ClassRate = req.query.ClassRate;
var ClassImage = req.query.ClassImage;
var ClientID = req.query.ClientID;
```

Comment: you can use [Multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) to achieve the same.

Comment: @Pradeepb. i thought multer is used to upload the file to server. can i use it to access the file from request object? i actually want to save the file to database

Comment: I am not sure. I thought you were asking how to upload the file on server side. I had used multer to save the pdf file on the server(in some folder).